# Tracking the mouse position on the QGraphicsItem

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I have a subclass of `QGraphicsItem` and I want to track mouse position every time I hover the mouse on that Item alone and it should give the relative position to the `QGraphicsItem`. I know, how to handle this when there is `QWidget` (using `QWidget.setMouseTracking`) and `QMainWindow` (by installing event filters), but I cant figure out how to do it for `QGraphicsItem`. The mouse move event is only triggered, when there is mouse press event, but that's not what is want. I want a trigger whenever I hover on that `QGraphicsItem`. Please provide your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [`my_item.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setAcceptHoverEvents) to enable mouse move events without the mouse press event.

Note, this will not trigger a `mouseMoveEvent` but will instead trigger a `hoverMoveEvent` (along with `hoverEnterEvent` and `hoverLeaveEvent` when you initially move the mouse over or off the `QGraphicsItem` respectively. So make sure you override this method in your subclass of `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: thanks AGAIN!!! .. :) but I want mousemove event too, as I am using this, for panning.can I return mousemoveEvent in mouse hover event??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The `mouseMoveEvent` will still be triggered when you click and move. Maybe you need to update your question with exactly what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: I have a QGraphicsItem, that will zoom and pan (using mouse move events). I have just learnt PyQt4. And I am developing a small customizer. Thnks.. :)